# Received data from JSON into function and save in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i want to received this data(`orderNumber,receiptNumber,Truck,driverName,jsonData` into my function and save it, i tried to receive this data but does not coming

Ajax Function

```
 $("#btnSaveOrder").on('click', function(e){

var orderNumber=$("#order_no").val();
var receiptNumber=$("#receiptNumber").val();
var Truck=$("#Truck").val();
var driverName=$("#driverName").val();
var jsonData=convertTableToJson();

$.ajax('/api/loading/saveLoadingsData', {
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    orderNumber:orderNumber,
    receiptNumber:receiptNumber,
     Truck:Truck,
    driverName:driverName,
    items:jsonData
  },
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {

    alert("Data Saved");
    document.location.reload(true);

  },
  error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);

  }
});


});

  var convertTableToJson = function(){
   var rows = [];
   $('table#tableSelectedItems tr').each(function(i, n){
    if (i!=0) {
    var $row = $(n);
    rows.push({
      itemId: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
      itemName:   $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
      quantity:    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),

    });
  }
});
return rows;
};
```

my controller

```
public function saveLoadingsData(Request $request) {

    $data=json_encode($request->all());

    dd($data);
  }
```

My Api

> Route::post('loading/saveLoadingsData', 'LoadingController@saveLoadingsData');

my view from

[image]
what can i do to received those data and save it into table `Loading`

Comment: what is your `dd($data);` result?

Comment: Did't you forgot to create new route in your api.php?

Comment: @Hossein does not print anything

Comment: @Viktor don't understand which router

Comment: anything or empty array? try `dd($request);` also.

Comment: @Hossein anything, if i click `btnSaveOrder` no anything Display

Comment: I think it's because of api.php default middleware. move your route to web.php and then remove `api/` from `'/api/loading/saveLoadingsData'`. don't forget to add csrf

Comment: @Hossein, i do but nothing change,, but keep in my that in my blade form i dn't include  `form tag`, i just call that button id only

Comment: so check your api with postman

Comment: @Hossein, my api return `"[]"`